# Cannot delete object property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

```
obj = {a: []}
```

I want to delete `obj.a`. This code works

```
if(!obj.a.length)
    delete obj.a //work
```

This is not

```
function _delete(o) {
    if(!o.length)
      delete o 
}

_delete(obj.a) //not work
```

Any way to make it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't delete `[]`, which is all that you pass to the function.

You can create a function like

```
function _delete(obj, prop) {
    if (obj[prop] && ! obj[prop].length) delete obj[prop];
}
```

and call it with

```
_delete(obj, 'a');
```

I'd also add a check for what the property is, and if it exists at all. As you seem to target an array, add a check if it's an array that gets passed:

```
function _delete(obj, prop) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[prop]) && ! obj[prop].length) delete obj[prop];
}
```

Comment: might want a check if property exists also so as not to throw error checking length of undefined